# Is there a simple way to transfer IMAP mail between servers using local Mail client?

Tags: email, imap, nameservers

I am in the process of moving my domains from one server to another.  I am looking for a straightforward way of transferring my emails across.  Both accounts are IMAP and both have the same email address and mailserver, i.e. mail.domain.com, but with a different user name and password.

I am wondering if I can simply change the username and password in my email client (Mail on Mac OSX) once the new nameservers have propagated, and the mail folders that I have locally will synchronise with the new server?

If this is not the correct procedure, what is the best/simplest way of proceeding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add both accounts simultaenously to a client, and then move messages from one to the other.  The mail won't copy on their own just by changing the mail server, because the it's a client view onto the server, not a synchronization algorithm.

However, this question isnt' appropriate for stackoverflow, which is for /programming/ questions.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for inappropriate placement of question